# How to required tuple from database using JSP

Tags: mysql, jsp

I need to retrieve as user specifies in previous page So I written code in this may But I got that

Unable to connect to databasejava.sql.SQLException: you have an error in your SQL syntax;check the manual that corresponds to your MYSQL server version for right syntax to use near '==t)'

My code

```
   <%@ page import="java.sql.*" %> 
   <%@ page import="java.io.*" %> 
   <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"  pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
   <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
   <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn" %>

   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
   <html>
   <head>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
   <title>Insert title here</title>
   </head>
   <body>
   <%
    try 
     {
      String t=request.getParameter("val");
      String connectionURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/tables";
      Connection connection = null; 
      Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); 
      connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL, "root", "");
      Statement st = connection.createStatement();
            String query="select * from details where sno==t)";
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);
            if(!connection.isClosed())
            {
                while(rs.next())
                {       
                 out.println(rs.getString(1)); 
                 out.println(rs.getString(2)); 
                 out.println(rs.getString(3)); 
                 out.println("<br>");
                }
             }
         } 
             connection.close();
       }
       catch(Exception ex)
      {
         out.println("Unable to connect to database"+ex);
       }        
     }
   }
   %>
   </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: ya i did both but none worked out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comparison operator in MySQL is `=` not `==`.

**code snippet:**

```
int param = Integer.parseInt(t);
String query="select * from details where sno = "+param;
System.out.println("query="+query);    
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);
```

In fact you should specify like below to comply with the datatypes:

```
out.println(rs.getInt("sno")); 
out.println(rs.getInt("Id")); 
out.println(rs.getString("name"));
out.println(rs.getInt("mobile"));
```

Comment: with this i got no error but een tuples were not retrieved

Comment: Share the table structure of `details` table.

Comment: details (sno integer (Auto increment PRIMARY KEY),Id integer,name varchar ,mobile integer)

Comment: Which tuple you are looking for retrieving? Since `sno` is `integer` you have to provide an int value to match.

Comment: so i should take t=Integer.parseInt();

Comment: Thank you I got it

Comment: In fact you should specify which data type you are expecting like the last code snippet in my answer.